# How to append pandas dataframe to_csv with different columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a pandas data frame read from csv file (data.csv). After processing data, I have another data frame less number of columns than in the data.csv file but still has same column name. Now I want to append new data frame to data.csv file.
I don't know how to append and merge by column name.

data.csv file has structure

```
ID    name   email  
1     John   j@gmail.com  
2     Ann    a@gmail.com
```

New data frame has structure

```
ID    name  
1     Smith  
2     Kov  
3     Jane
```

Now I want to write new data frame to data.csv file, result must be

```
ID     Name      email  
1      John      j@gmail.com  
2      Ann       a@gmail.com  
3      Smith   
4      Kov  
5      Jane
```

Comment: What is your expected output supposed to be like?

Comment: `pd.concat([df_old, df_new], ignore_index=True)`?

Answer (score 0):

The approach here isn't to append the existing csv, but rather to write over it, in this case with the original data as part of your output. If you read your original csv as `df` and your new dataframe is `df2`:

```
df3 = df.append(df2)
df3.to_csv("data.csv")
```

or on one line:

```
df.append(df2).to_csv("data.csv")
```

The `pd.DataFrame.append` method works how you want it to when the column names match. Of course, I would recommend saving to another filename at first to make sure you're getting the output you want, and once you're happy with it changing your code to overwrite data.csv, lest you accidentally destroy data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I also solved my problem as same way as you.
df2.reindex(columns=df.columns).to_csv("data.csv", index=False, header=False, mode="a")